# How to select replicated items in a list with linq?

Tags: vb.net, linq

Hy Guys!

I have a list of "ObjDay" which could have replicated items. How can I select them?

ObjDay is:

```
    Public class ObjDay
        _date
        ...
    End Class
```

I tried to do:

```
replicatedItems = From d In ObjDaysList _
               Order By d._date _
               Group d By d._date Into newGroupOfObjDays = Group _
               Where newGroupOfObjDays.Count > 1 _
               Select newGroupOfObjDays
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Can't convert object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[VB$AnonymousType_0`2[System.DateTime,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ObjDay]], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ObjDay]]'
>   in type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ObjDay]'.

---

Tks for help!

Comment: Isn't date a type?  Shouldn't you assign it an actual variable name?

Comment: Scottie, it was translated from Portuguse. "date" is a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting groups, and trying to assign it to a `List(Of ObjDay)`. That won't work. You could do:

```
'Get groups of duplicate items
Dim groups = From d In ObjDaysList _
             Order By d._date _
             Group d By d._date Into newGroupOfObjDays = Group _
             Where newGroupOfObjDays.Count > 1 _
             Select newGroupOfObjDays

'Get all items from these groups with SelectMany
replicatedItems = groups.SelectMany(Function(item) item).ToList
```

Comment: I created a test program and it does get all replicated items... Can't think of a reason why you'd get different results...